# How to inherit the div height from parent div without flex to come into play

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to insert a grid inside my main page. I am dividing my main page for two containers, one for a header and one for the grid. I specified a particular height for the header and I am expecting the grid should fit in the remaining container.

The problem I am seeing here is, if there are more records in the grid, the grid expands inside the main page with a scroll bar on the page.

I want the grid to show inside the page view only and not increase the page height. i.e., if there are more records, I want the grid to show the scrollbar and not the main page

I tried to remove flex, add "vh" height and height 100% but nothing seems to work. I also tried the overflow hidden but it hides the content of the grid. I need content but not overflow

```
containerStyle: {
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    paddingTop: viewPortWidth <= theme.sizes.Breakpoints.DimensionS ? undefined : "1.25rem",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: "1 0 auto",
    position: "relative",
},
```

Expected result
[image]

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your header has a fixed height you can use calc to set the height of the main content
e.g. height: calc(100vh - 80px); To make the main content scroll add overflow-y: scroll;

**Example:**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: orange;
  height: 123px;
  flex-shrink: 0;  
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: tomato;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {
  width: 29%;
  margin: 2%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: olive;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article>No room for me</article>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jakob, 
Thank you for response. This approach works. But however, when someone changes the header height, we got to come over here and change this height as well right? That wont be effective way to code right? Is there any generic way to this approach that work on this fix dynamically and wont be dependent on header height?

Comment: I've updated the example based on a flex-box wrapper (could be body)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to address my issue by taking this as base

Answer (score 0):

If you can use sass you can do something like:

HTML

```
<div class="header">...</div>
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="data-grid">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
$header-height:80px;
$gutter: 30px;
$header-gap: $gutter;
$page-gap:  $gutter;
$page-space: $gutter;
$subtract: $header-height + $header-gap + $page-gap;

.header{
   height: $header-height;
   margin-bottom: $header-gap;
}

.page-content {
   height: calc(100% - #{$subtract});
   padding: $page-space;
}

.data-grid {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/WWagOJ)

Comment: thank you for this approach i will keep this in mind for future implementations